Can't type anything in `iex -S mix`
I'm following the Elixir lesson on mix and got left with an iex session I can't type anything into except [Return] and [Ctrl]+[C].
Repro:
> mix new example
...
> cd example
> iex -S mix

IEx opens but I can't type anything. I'm assuming I should be able to type and run Example.hello(), but the only thing I can do is to type [Return] (once) or exit with [Ctrl]+[C].
When I run iex -S mix run --no-start it works as expected. Maybe the lesson is just outdated?
> iex -v
IEx 1.16.3 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 26)
> mix -v
Erlang/OTP 26 [erts-14.2.5] [source] [64-bit] [smp:32:32] [ds:32:32:10] [async-threads:1] [jit:ns]

Mix 1.16.3 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 26)

Update
Ok this somehow seems to be connected to the _build folder. Sometimes I'm able to use iex -S mix normally once, but only iex -S mix run --no-start works the second time. Sometimes even that won't work. And sometimes it helps to delete _build first. But I can't reproduce this consistently. I'm just super confused.

issue posted by someone on github https://github.com/elixirschool/elixirschool/issues/3015

it works just fine on my machine. Try mix clean and then try iex -S mix.

@dinesh_pandikona mix clean didn't help. Maybe it's a problem with windows terminal?

saddening to see a beginner to face this issue which is totally uncommon. can try building the project from scratch in different directory? when you run, also see how much space it is taking on the machine.

@dinesh_pandikona don't worry, it's not a blocking issue. After the couple of tries it usually works with one of the described workarounds. I tried creating a fresh project multiple times. Or do you mean trying a different root directory or even drive? What do you mean by "space"? Disk space or memory usage?
